# angular js - ng-change not working for checkbox with make switch class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Html View**:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       id="checkbox1"
       class="make-switch" 
       ng-init="option=true" 
       ng-change="getInput(option)" 
       ng-model="option" 
       data-on-text="&nbsp;Individual&nbsp;" 
       data-off-text="&nbsp;Company&nbsp;" input >
```

**Controller file**:

```
$scope.getInput = function(option){
    alert(option);
}
```

I am using the **checkbox** with make-switch class. It's not getting fired. The `ng-change` directive is not affecting any changes.

Comment: Try this:
`<input type="checkbox" class="make-switch" ng-init="option=true" ng-change="getInput(option)" ng-model="option" data-on-text="&nbsp;Individual&nbsp;" data-off-text="&nbsp;Company&nbsp;"  id="checkbox1">`

Comment: is your input is inside ng-if directive ?

Comment: No i never use ng-if for this view.

Comment: You can use `ng-checked` for this instead `ng-change`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, initialize your option variable in your controller, like this:

```
$scope.option = false;
```

Comment: hi sletheren. ng-change is not affects.

Comment: angular.module('MetronicApp').controller('leadDetailsController', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $timeout) {
  $("[name='makeSwitch']").bootstrapSwitch();

$scope.select = true;
$scope.leadSelect = false;

$scope.option = false;

//Next Click
$scope.nextView = function(leadSelect){
 $scope.select = false;
 $scope.Individual = true;
}

$scope.getInput = function(option){
    alert(option);
}


});

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('MetronicApp').controller('leadDetailsController', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $timeout) {
  $("[name='makeSwitch']").bootstrapSwitch();

$scope.select = true;
$scope.leadSelect = false;

$scope.option = false;

//Next Click
$scope.nextView = function(leadSelect){
    $scope.select = false;
    $scope.Individual = true;
}

$scope.getInput = function(option){
    alert(option);
}


});
```